# Custom loss function in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I have three simple questions.

1. What will happen if my custom loss function is not differentiable? Will pytorch through error or do something else?
2. If I declare a loss variable in my custom function which will represent the final loss of the model, should I put `requires_grad = True` for that variable? or it doesn't matter? If it doesn't matter, then why?
3. I have seen people sometimes write a separate layer and compute the loss in the `forward` function. Which approach is preferable, writing a function or a layer? Why?

I need a clear and nice explanation to these questions to resolve my confusions. Please help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let me have a go.

1. This depends on what you mean by "non-differentiable". The first definition that makes sense here is that PyTorch doesn't know how to compute gradients. If you try to compute gradients nevertheless, this will raise an error. The two possible scenarios are:

   a) You're using a custom PyTorch operation for which gradients have not been implemented, e.g. `torch.svd()`. In that case you will get a `TypeError`:

   ```
   import torch
   from torch.autograd import Function
   from torch.autograd import Variable

   A = Variable(torch.randn(10,10), requires_grad=True)
   u, s, v = torch.svd(A) # raises TypeError
   ```

   b) You have implemented your own operation, but did not define `backward()`. In this case, you will get a `NotImplementedError`:

   ```
   class my_function(Function): # forgot to define backward()

       def forward(self, x):
           return 2 * x

   A = Variable(torch.randn(10,10))
   B = my_function()(A)
   C = torch.sum(B)
   C.backward() # will raise NotImplementedError
   ```

   The second definition that makes sense is "mathematically non-differentiable". Clearly, an operation which is mathematically not differentiable should either not have a `backward()` method implemented or a sensible sub-gradient. Consider for example `torch.abs()` whose `backward()` method returns the subgradient 0 at 0:

   ```
   A = Variable(torch.Tensor([-1,0,1]),requires_grad=True)
   B = torch.abs(A)
   B.backward(torch.Tensor([1,1,1]))
   A.grad.data
   ```

   For these cases, you should refer to the PyTorch documentation directly and dig out the `backward()` method of the respective operation directly.
2. It doesn't matter. The use of `requires_grad`is to avoid unnecessary computations of gradients for subgraphs. If there’s a single input to an operation that requires gradient, its output will also require gradient. Conversely, only if all inputs don’t require gradient, the output also won’t require it. Backward computation is never performed in the subgraphs, where all Variables didn’t require gradients.

   Since, there are most likely some `Variables` (for example parameters of a subclass of `nn.Module()`), your `loss` Variable will also require gradients automatically. However, you should notice that exactly for how `requires_grad` works (see above again), you can only change `requires_grad` for leaf variables of your graph anyway.
3. All the custom PyTorch loss functions, are subclasses of `_Loss` which is a  subclass of `nn.Module`. [See here.](http://pytorch.org/docs/_modules/torch/nn/modules/loss.html#MSELoss) If you'd like to stick to this convention, you should subclass `_Loss` when defining your custom loss function. Apart from consistency, one advantage is that your subclass will raise an `AssertionError`, if you haven't marked your target variables as `volatile` or `requires_grad = False`. Another advantage is that you can nest your loss function in `nn.Sequential()`, because its a `nn.Module` I would recommend this approach for these reasons.

Comment: I removed the question actually because I solved it. But can you help me in this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44580450/cuda-vs-dataparallel-why-the-difference ?